# What is this disease with sticky transparent liquid and brown spots on leaves?

Tags: diseases

here is a picture of the plant, a shefflera.

It has some very sticky transparent liquid on many leaves, and also brown spots. The spots themselves are kind of "dry" and mostly located at the leaves knots.

[image: picture of shefflera with sticky liquid and brown spot on leaves]

It seems that the entire plant is becoming infested by this problem.

Searching for answers, I've found this question about "sticky citrus leaves", that looks very similar. But it's not a citrus, so I made my own question.

citrus question link:
[How to cure sticky citrus leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22748/how-to-cure-sticky-citrus-leaves)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem to the citrus link you gave - it's scale insect infestation. You can either use insecticidal soap as a spray, or neem, or one of the range of pesticides available on the market that treat for scale. Since this plant is not producing edible fruit, you are less restricted in your choice of treatments, but if you use a proper pesticide, I suggest you take the plant outdoors, but not in sunlight, to spray it. Not sure what products are available where you are, so I can't make a recommendation, but here in the UK, I'd risk using Provado Bug Clear Ultra, but just make sure whatever you choose is effective for scale. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/schefflera-pests-26994.html